# Google Glass, Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, google-glass

I've been given a project to help with, but I cannot get it to work, and those who gave it to me are as stumped as I am. We're working on making an android software for Google Glass, using Android Studio 2.1.2. Also we've been setting up SDK and such.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19'
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
dependencies {
}
```

That's the main build.gradle file. Then, in the app-folder, if that's important, this file lies. Also build.gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
repositories {
jcenter()
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19'
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    final def config = defaultConfig {
        unimportant stuff
    }
    config
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            things
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        hopefully unimportant
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
dependencies {
    a considerable amount
}
```

Now, I get the problem "Gradle DSL method not found: android()". There are more questions on here that ask about that. So, following the advice of those who answer, I attempted deleting the android and dependency things from the top gradle. I ended up with the following error. "Failed to set up SDK. Module 'app': platform 'Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19' not found." This despite everything else is set up.

Now, note, the code as it looks obviously works, as it does for those who I got the code from. Something is very wrong on my end. I'm asking the good people of the internet, do you know what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can only configure the `android` extension object for projects that you have applied the android plugin. Since you have not applied the android plugin to the root project, the `android` extension object does not exist in that project and therefore can't be configured. I'm guessing you meant to do the following in the main/root build.gradle

```
subprojects {
    if (plugins.hasPlugin('com.android.application')) {
        android {
            // common configuration for all android modules goes here
        }
    }
}
```

Another note on style, since this is in the root project:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

You can remove this from the subproject

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

Comment: It makes the statement "Gradle DSL method not found: 'hasPlugin()'."

Comment: Changed to `plugins.hasPlugin(...)`

Comment: Hm. With that done, I now get "Error:Module 'app': platform 'Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19' not found.", which sounds like a separate problem to me. But, that was one of the things the android thing did compileSdkVersion on. That's also the same problem I got when I just deleted android and dependencies from the root project. ... Gosh, this is problematic. I assume this meant it didn't pass the hasPlugin if-statement. How do I fix that? Just including "apply plugin: 'com.android.application'" did not work when I tried earlier.

Comment: Get it working first without any "common" config in the root `build.gradle` and refactor common logic out once it's working. Perhaps these [android-gradle-examples](https://github.com/Goddchen/Android-Gradle-Examples) can help

Comment: I solved it somehow, I'm not entirely sure how but I followed couple of different suggestions on the internet and eventually got something working. Not sure what of what I did that solved it, unfortunately. Thank you very much for your help. I was in quite a bind. Haha.